# Syntax error in HSQLDB 2.3.2 with Hibernate 4.3.6

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, hsqldb

I'm using Spring 4.0.6 + Spring data 1.6.2 + Hibernate 4.3.6 + Hsqldb 2.3.2 with my app that now is using H2 db.

These are the relevant part of my jpa configuration:

```
<property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
    <property name="url"
        value="jdbc:hsqldb:file:~/db/test" />
```

...

```
<property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect" />
```

...

Unfortunally when my app starts an try to create the db I've these errors:

```
29/09/2014 19:39:13 ERROR SchemaUpdate:236 - HHH000388: Unsuccessful: create table 

Comunicazione (id bigint generated by default as identity (start with 1), creatoDa varchar(255), dataInserimento timestamp, dataUltimaModifica timestamp, modificatoDa varchar(255), ENTITY_UID varchar(36) not null, version integer, codiceEsterno varchar(255) not null, cognome varchar(255), email varchar(255), nome varchar(255), preferenzaEmail VARCHAR(255) default 'NO' not null, preferenzaSms VARCHAR(255) default 'NO' not null, preferenzaTelefonata VARCHAR(255) default 'NO' not null, sesso varchar(255), sorgenteAggiornamento varchar(255), statoEmail VARCHAR(255) default 'DA_INVIARE' not null, statoSms VARCHAR(255) default 'DA_INVIARE' not null, statoTelefonata VARCHAR(255) default 'DA_EFFETTUARE' not null, telefonoCasa varchar(255), telefonoCellulare varchar(255), telefonoUfficio varchar(255), tentativiTelefonata INT(10) default 0 not null, titolo varchar(255), template_id bigint not null, primary key (id))
29/09/2014 19:39:13 ERROR SchemaUpdate:237 - unexpected token: (
29/09/2014 19:39:13 ERROR SchemaUpdate:236 - HHH000388: Unsuccessful: create table Log (id bigint generated by default as identity (start with 1), creatoDa varchar(255), dataInserimento timestamp, dataUltimaModifica timestamp, modificatoDa varchar(255), ENTITY_UID varchar(36) not null, version integer, posizione clob(255), testo LONGTEXT, tipologia varchar(255) not null, titolo LONGTEXT, primary key (id))
29/09/2014 19:39:13 ERROR SchemaUpdate:237 - type not found or user lacks privilege: LONGTEXT
```

Seems that the syntax of the dialect is wrong. It's quite strange.

Some ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

The problem were in the definition of a @Column in the entity where I used:

```
@Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "INT(10) default 0")
```

there is a mysql compatible syntax. However HSQLDB need a different definition of the column:

```
@Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "INT default 0")
```